# SQL Querying with New Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my database I have Timestamps, Source, ID, and Value all in one table.
Essentially it's displayed like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Query</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Timestamp</td>
<td>Source</td>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Value</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have a ton of different Sources and IDs, so I was curious if I could create a query where the timestamp is shared between two different Sources and IDs.  The resultant table from the query I would be looking for is something like this:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Query</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Timestamp</td>
    <td>Value at Source = 123, ID = 456</td>
    <td>Value at Source = 789, ID = 000</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is this something that is possible to achieve, or would I be better off pulling this and rearranging the data somewhere else?

Comment: This sounds like you want to `ORDER BY` your results and display groups of timestamps together.

Answer (score 0):

You join the table against itself to find records which match on certain values and differ on others:

```
SELECT a.Timestamp,
  a.Value AS Value_1, a.Source AS Source_1, a.ID AS ID_1,
  b.Value AS Value_2, b.Source AS Source_2, b.ID AS ID_2
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN MyTable b
ON a.Timestamp = b.Timestamp
AND a.Source <> b.Source
AND a.ID <> b.ID
```

It's not quite clear from your question what exactly the output should look like, but you ought to be able to play with the selected columns to get what you want.

You should also have indexes on the three columns used in the join if performance is important.